# Unable to use IIS Windows Auth with Custom flow

Tags: asp.net, iis, identityserver3

## Background

Our product consumes a proprietary single sign-on (SSO) solution owned by our customer and uses Identity Server to handle authorization. Our product uses a `Custom` flow and implemented `ICustomGrantValidator` in order to integrate with the proprietary SSO solution. We have a mimic of this SSO for use in our development environment.

We want to deploy a development version of our app to a public facing site for our customer to be able to demo new capabilities. We ideally want to use Windows Authorization to only allow select people to view the site.

## Problem

When Windows Auth is enabled on IIS Identity Server tries to handle it, but it is unsuccessful because it hasn't been configured to do so.

We would like to avoid re-writing our sign-on to also allow Identity Server to handle Windows Auth logins and map the Active Directory user to our SSO users. This is especially important because adding this functionality would drastically change the scope of this task.

## Question

Is there a way to configure Identity Server to ignore Windows Auth requests made by IIS? Currenlty Windows Auth is configured at the IIS level and not the ASP.NET level. There is a deny rule for unauthenticated users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few different attempts at changing the flow of our login I stumbled upon this post: [Using a Custom Flow for Authentication #2760](http://Using%20a%20Custom%20Flow%20for%20Authentication%20#2760)

In addition to using a `Custom` flow with an `ICustomGrantValidator` I added an override to `PreAuthenticateAsync` and handled our integration with the SSO there. This alleviated the issue and looks good so far.